# showing php date in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've two datepickers of start date and end date. I've start date and end date as well in php. I want to set this start date and end date in jquery datepicker. If my start date is 15/07/2015 then the start date calendar should start from 15th july all the dates before 15th july should be disabled, if end date is 20/07/2015 so the end date calendar should be from 15th july to 20th july. User should not able to select date before or after start date and end date. I've tried so many things like setting min date, setting default date and then on change of start date setting end date but noting seems to working. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
$('#check_in').datepicker({ minDate: "2015/07/19" });
```

Comment: Did you tried something.. where is the code. ?

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
$('#check_in').datepicker({ minDate: new Date(year,month-1,date)});
```

In your case:

```
$('#check_in').datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2015,7-1,19)});
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas for a quick response i'd set the max and min date and its working fine now. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
       <script>
                 $("#check_in").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',minDate:'2015-07-15' ,maxDate:'2015-07-27'});

       </script>
```